# Dell Latitude 630 is not powering off after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shutdown

I have a laptop with 32 bit system and ubuntu 12.04 installed in it.
I upgraded it to ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and my laptop is going to the shut down page but it isn't powering off. I always press the power button and do force shut down. What is wrong and is there any alternative way to power off my laptop. I am using Dell Latitude 630.Or can i contact dell customer care.

If any one knows the way to power off please send me a mail.

THANKYOU